# Java - How can I revise my replacePlaceholder method so that it no longer has an index out of bounds error for my mad libs program?

Tags: java, string, placeholder

ISSUE SOLVED, CODE BELOW NOT UPDATED
I have solved the issue I had with this code with the help of one helpful user. The code below is not updated.

```
    // replacePlaceholder method
    private String replacePlaceholder(String template, String placeholder, String replacement)
    {
        String newTemplate = "";
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < template.length(); i++)
        {
             if(count == 0 && template.substring(i, i + placeholder.length()).equals(placeholder))
            {
                newTemplate += replacement;
                count++;
            }
            else if(count != 1)
            {
                newTemplate += template.substring(i, i + 1);
            }
        }
        return newTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: go through a debugger, you will find out yourself

Comment: The message tells you that you try to use invalid index values within that string. Simply **print** the string, and the indexes you want to use. Then fix the logic that comes up with numbers such as -1 ;-) ... or improve your question, by looking at [mcve].

Comment: What is this method supposed to do, exactly? If you just need to replace sub-strings in another string there's the `replace(String placeholder, String replacement)` method.

Comment: This method is supposed to replace a given placeholder in a template with a given replacement String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by the comments, you should just use `String.replace(String, String)` or `String.replaceAll(String, String)` instead of writing it yourself. There are a number of issues with your current implementation:

- `template.substring(i, placeholder.length() + 1)` should be `template.substring(i, i + placeholder.length())`. Otherwise, your `beginIndex` can be larger than `endIndex`.
- If template ends with half a placeholder, `substring` will fail because `endIndex` is too large.
- `aaa[placeholder]aaa` will be turned into `aaareplacementplaceholder]aaa` with you current code as you do not skip the rest of the placeholder.
- A second placeholder will not be replaced as you say `count++` but never reset it, making your `if` always go to `else`.
- possibly more

Comment: Solved all problems except for "aaa[placeholder]aaa will be turned into aaareplacementplaceholder]aaa with you current code as you do not skip the rest of the placeholder." Also, I only want one placeholder to be replaced at a time, that is why I have "count" never being reset.

Comment: @mini23 I see. Maybe you can then call `newTemplate += template.substring(i + placeHolder.length()); break;` after adding the replacement. Then you do not need `count` anymore.

Comment: Got it. I'm still stuck on how to solve the issue with not replacing the rest of the placeholder.

Comment: @mini23 It happens because you continue looping every single character of `template`. It should be solved with what I wrote above: As soon as you find the placeholder (i.e. in your `if->true` block), you should append the `replacement`, append the rest of `template` (`substring` starting at **`placeholder.length()+1`**) and **`break` the loop** (which will prevent adding the rest of `placeholder`).